# Can XAML "deduce" inheritance from C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, styles

I wonder if XAML is somehow able to "deduce" the C# inheritance. Let me explain:

I have these two C# classes:

```
public class AStyleSelector: StyleSelector {
    public Style aStyle { get; set; }

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        //....
    }
}

public class BStyleSelector : AStyleSelector{
    public Style bStyle { get; set; }

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var tmp = aStyle; // this is null
        //....
    }
}
```

`BStyleSelector` inherits from `AStyleSelector` which inherits from `StyleSelector`. They both implement `SelectStyle`.

Then I have the next in a XAML file:

Here I defined two styles:

```
<Style // to be used in both AStyleSelector and BStyleSelector
    x:Key="StyleA"
    //... some styles
</Style>


<Style // to be used only in BStyleSelector
    x:Key="StyleB"
    //... some styles
</Style>
```

Here I am binding to C# classes and pointing to the defined Styles:

```
<AStyleSelector //pointing to the above C# class
    aStyle="{StaticResource StyleA}" />

<BStyleSelector //pointing to the above C# class
    bStyle="{StaticResource StyleB}" />
```

Now, the problem is, in the method SelectStyle from BStyleSelector, I cannot access the value of aStyle. It is returning null.

I know there is a quick fix (that works correctly) which is this:

```
<BStyleSelector
    aStyle="{StaticResource StyleA}" // adding this line
    bStyle="{StaticResource StyleB}" />
```

But I don't want to reference the `StyleA` twice. I was expecting that XAML would deduce it's value because `BStyleSelector` inherits it from `AStyleSelector`.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: inheritance doesn't mean that all instances have the same values of the same properties. it doesn't make sense. you have to initialize property in each instance

Answer (score 0):

Then base class `AStyleSelector` only defines a property `aStyle` with a getter and a setter that is inherited in the derived class `BStyleSelector`. The base class `AStyleSelector` **does not assign a value** to this property in its constructor, so when you create a new instance of it, the property `aStyle` will be the default value, `null`. The same applies to creating a new instance of the derived class `BStyleSelector`.

The XAML code below does exactly that, it creates a new instance, where the value for property `aStyle` is `null`, since it is not assinged any other value in the constructor. After construction, the property will be set to the static resource `StyleA` via its setter. Remember it is only set **on this instance** of `AStyleSelector`.

```
<AStyleSelector aStyle="{StaticResource StyleA}" />
```

The same happens to `BStyleSelector`, but there you only set property `bStyle`, so the inherited property will still get its default value `null` in this **newly created instance,** too. There is no *invisible* connection between both instances of `AStyleSelector` and `BStyleSelector` that would copy `aStyle` to this instance.

```
<BStyleSelector bStyle="{StaticResource StyleB}" />
```

Therefore, the solution to your problem is the code that you already have. You have to create a instances of `BStyleSelector` and explicitly assign `aStyle` and `StyleB`.

```
<BStyleSelector aStyle="{StaticResource StyleA}"
                bStyle="{StaticResource StyleB}" />
```

---

Just as a note, an alternative to holding a property of `Style` in the style selector could be to resolve the resource in the `SelectStyle` method itself. For that, the `container` has to be of type `FrameworkElement` so you can call the [`FindResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource?view=net-5.0) method with the resource key, e.g.:

```
public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
   var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)container;
   var aStyle = (Style)frameworkElement.FindResource("StyleA");

   return aStyle;
}
```